# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : differing length

Tags: r

Getting acquintated with mutate right now, and I wanted to inquire about why this is happening and how I could go about fixing this.

Currently I'm creating a dataframe with 8 rows:

```
modelOption_RT <- data.frame(
  typeID = rep(1:2, each = 4),
  ID = 1:8,
  modelOption = c("good", "avg", "bad", "marginCost", 
                  "year1Premium")[c(1:5, 1:3)],
  descrip = c("Favorable", "Average", "Adverse", "Margin Cost", 
              "Year 1 Premium")[c(1:5, 1:3)],
  vals = sort(round(runif(8, min=0, max=1), digits = 2), decreasing = FALSE)[c(1:5,1:3)]) %>%
  mutate(vals = replace(vals, modelOption == "year1Premium", 
                        runif(1, min=0, max=10000)),

  modelOption_RT %>% mutate(Losses = ifelse(typeID == 2 & modelOption != "year1Premium", 
                                            vals*10000000, vals))
                  )
```

once I run it, I get:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `modelOption_RT %>% mutate(Losses = ifelse(typeID == 2 & modelOption != 
    "year1Premium", vals * 10000000, vals))` must be length 8 (the number of rows) or one, not 6
```

The last line using mutate shouldn't generate 6 rows, it should generate 8. All that last line is doing is multiplying conditional values by a number, and leaving the other values so it's not taking values away - which is why I'm confused about why the length would differ.

When I run the last mutate line outside of the dataframe function seperately, it does the job just fine. But throw it in the function like I have, it gives me a length issue. Why is that?

Comment: If you're trying to run this code exactly as you've pasted it here, you've just got some very simple errors that need to be fixed. Change the comma after the `runif()` statement to a parentheses and finish creating the `modelOption_RT` dataframe, delete the final `)`, then `mutate()` the `Losses` column. Also, you could just mutate `Losses` in the initial dataframe creation.

Comment: Great, got it! Made the suggested changes and took out the last modelOption_RT variable to just connect the pipe to the previous mutate and it worked out. Thank you Steven!